# How can I open an url link without opening a browser (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android-studio, http

I need some help for opening an URL link, yeah I know...

I use this link to start recording on my GoPro HERO 5.
But for some reasons I tried multiple ways of doing it.

1st method :

```
URL _url = new URL("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
URLConnection _urlConnection = _url.Openconnection;
_urlConnection.connect();
```

2nd method :

```
_url = new URL("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
_http = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
_http.connect()
```

3rd method :

```
DatagramSocket _mySocket = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress _myAdr = InetAddress.getByName("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
DatagramPacket _myPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, _myAdr);

_mySocket.receive(_myPacket);
```

4th method :

```
WebView.LoadUrl("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
```

the 4th way kind of worked but it opened a browser window which I don't want to.

Comment: have you created webView in your XML. If yes, add these also in your question.

Comment: ```
WebView _myWebView;
WebView _myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

_myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
```


I noticed I made a mistake, it was not LoadFromUri but LoadUrl, LoadFromUri is for VideoView ^^

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Got net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED
something to do in the xml it seems

Comment: just add this line `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside your `</application>` tag in your Menifest.xml

Comment: yeah did it and it works wonders, just got to figure out for the UDP part now, but thanks for you help ^^